# How do I change my GitHub account on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, github

So, let's say I have 2 emails:

1. College Email @colledge
2. Personal Email @gmail

Until now, what I have done is create a repo on my @college GitHub account and then clone in VS to commit all the changes and sync it, and it works fabulously.
But the problem is actually my @gmail account is connected with VS so all my commits are from @gmail to repo of @college

I have both of them logged in on Vs but don't know how to switch to @college account on VS.

**Do any of you have solution regarding this...**
Instead I migrate all my @college github work to @gmail GitHub which I want to do from sometime but not been able to in fear that i will loose all my prior progress on GitHub.

I tried reading things on Google but not been able to find a proper solution.

Comment: There are two things to consider, but they are independent of each other: 1. which name and email is added as author to commits, 2. which account is used for login with GitHub